# call method in a subclass of UIView

Tags: iphone, class, uiview, delegates, subclass

I've got a UIViewController and an own class, a subclass of UIView.

In my ViewController I make a instance of the uiview.
If I tap the uiview a function gets called within it and an overlay appears.
TO get rid of that overlay later the user has to tap somewhere on the screen(besides the instance of my class)

How do I tell my class to dismiss the overlay? I already thought of delegate.

So my thoughts were to make a MyUIViewControllerdelegate. If my viewcontroller receives a tap the delegate should be called. THe only problem is how do I tell my subclass that it should receive that delegate? I Have no instance of my viewcontroller in my subclass so I can not set the delegate.

Any Ideas? Hope my problem is clear :)

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The only problem is how do I tell my
>   subclass that it should receive that
>   delegate? I Have no instance of my
>   viewcontroller in my subclass so I can
>   not set the delegate.

MyUIView.h:

```
@protocol MyUIViewDelegate;

@interface MyUIView : UIView
{
    ...
    id<MyUIViewDelegate> delegate;
    ...
}

...
@property (nonatomic, assign) id<MyUIViewDelegate> delegate;
...

@end

@protocol MyUIViewDelegate <NSObject>
- (void)myUIViewDidFinish:(MyUIView*)myUIView;
@end
```

MyUIView.m:

```
...
@synthesize delegate;
...

- (void)dismiss
{
    [delegate myUIViewDidFinish:self];
}
```

MyUIViewController.h:

```
#import "MyUIView.h"

@interface MyUIViewController : UIViewController <MyUIViewDelegate>
{
    ...
    MyUIView* myOverlay;
    ...
}

...
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet MyUIView* myOverlay;
...

@end
```

MyUIViewController.m:

```
...
@synthesize myOverlay;
...

- (void)dealloc
{
    ...
    [myOverlay release];
    ...

    [super dealloc];
}

...

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    ...
    myOverlay.delegate = self;
    ...
}

...

- (void)showMyUIView
{
    // ... show myOverlay ...
}

...

#pragma mark MyUIViewDelegate Methods

- (void)myUIViewDidFinish:(MyUIView*)myUIView
{
    // ... hide myOverlay ...
}
```

Comment: First of all: Thanks for your work :)! So far I am understanding what you do. But how is it if i make multiple instances of my MyUIView?

I want to make as many as items count in an array.
So I cant set all of them in the @interface?